# How to save a dok matrix

Tags: python, matrix

How can I save a dok matrix and load it again later?

```
import scipy.sparse as sp


mat = sp.dok_matrix((df.shape[0], len(df['itemid'].unique())), dtype=np.float32)
for buyerid, itemid in zip(df['buyerid'], df['itemid']):
    mat[buyerid, itemid] = 1.0
# my try
sp.save_npz('/content/gdrive/My Drive/train_matrix.npz', mat)
.
.
.
# Loading the dok matrix
train_mat = sp.load_npz('spotify_train_matrix.npz')
```

The error

```
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/scipy/sparse/_matrix_io.py in save_npz(file, matrix, compressed)
     69         arrays_dict.update(row=matrix.row, col=matrix.col)
     70     else:
---> 71         raise NotImplementedError('Save is not implemented for sparse matrix of format {}.'.format(matrix.format))
     72     arrays_dict.update(
     73         format=matrix.format.encode('ascii'),

NotImplementedError: Save is not implemented for sparse matrix of format dok.
```

Could someone please help me to save and load the dok matrix which I'm creating?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you've noticed, you can't. But the notes on `dok_matrix` say:

> Can be efficiently converted to a coo_matrix once constructed.

and `coo_matrix` does support saving with `scipy.sparse.save_npz`. So I would suggest converting with `.tocoo()` and then saving. You can convert back after loading (if you wish).

Comment: thank you very much for your answer! May you can help me how I could convert it?

Comment: @MichaelSokoij I wrote that in the answer already. Call `.tocoo()` on the `dok_matrix` object.

Comment: Sorry, so with `sp.save_npz('train_matrix.npz', mat.tocoo())` right? And how do I convert it back `sp.load_npz(rain_matrix.npz')` ?

Comment: @MichaelSokoij Simply `sp.load_npz(rain_matrix.npz').todok()`.

Comment: Sometimes it's too easy, thanks for your help and time.